# Why does attaching to `SIGINT` on main process triggers `exit` event on child process

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this very basic setup (tested on both Windows 10 and MacOS Catalina):

```
// main.js

const fork = require('child_process').fork;

const cp = fork('./child.js');
cp.on('exit', (code, signal) => {
    console.log(
        'child process exited with ' + `code ${code} and signal ${signal}`
    );
});

//child.js

setInterval(() => {
    console.log('interval passed');
}, 3000);
```

Whenever I press `Ctrl+C`, both parent and child process are exited. **However, the `exit` event on the child process is not triggered.**

Now, if I attach a listener to the `SIGINT` signal on the main process, yet don't do anything in the event handler,

```
process.on('SIGINT', () => {});
```

when pressing `Ctrl+C`, both parent and child process are exited, and in this case the `exit` event on the child process is triggered with `code=null` and `signal=SIGINT`.

**Why is this behavior?**

I've done some research but still haven't found anything. I tried to attach the listener for `SIGINT` on child process without attaching the listener on the parent process, and the child received the signal (logged the message).

Also, [I found this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149756/90372) that states the following:

> When you press CTRL+C, your terminal emulator sends an ETX character
>   (end-of-text / 0x03). The TTY is configured such that when it receives
>   this character, **it sends a SIGINT to the foreground process group** of
>   the terminal.

So, if a child process is part of the foreground process group, maybe the signal is sent to it not through the parent process, but directly? Then what Jonas Wilms suggested could be true - the parent gets terminated before the child.

Comment: I assume in your first case the parent gets terminated before the child, so the event can never be triggered on the parent. Not sure though as this depends on Node internals (which someone has to look into)

Comment: @JonasWilms thanks for your thoughts, any way to test your assumption? I just attached the listener for `SIGINT` on a child process w/o attaching the listener on the parent process, and the child received the signal. Not sure if this adds any information.

Comment: I assume by adding the Sigint handler, The event queues get emptied till that handler gets reached. Therefore also the exit handlers from the child get executed. I tried to find the relevant parts in the NodeJS source and failed ...

Comment: @JonasWilms, appreciate your help!